# Upload Image data showing {} in Nodejs from ANgular js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am wrking on nodejs . i got response from frontend post request. all dataa is getting but upload file data showing null. {}
Pleasse see images

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG6mc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKE0I.png)

```
    const imageUpload = multer({
        storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log("asd");
            cb(null, "Attachments/");
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, new Date().valueOf() + "_" + file.originalname);
        },
    }),

    limits: { fileSize: 10000000 },
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (
            !file.originalname.match(
            /\.(jpg|JPG|webp|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF|pdf|PDF|docx|doc)$/
            )
        ) {
            req.fileValidationError = "Only Image, PDF and Word files are allowed!";
            return cb(null, false);
        } else {
            req.fileValidationError = "";
        }
            cb(null, true);
        },
    });

---



    // Add Property Details
    app.post('/addproperty', imageUpload.single("image"), (req, res) => {
        console.log("vicky", req.body.body.file);
        if (req.fileValidationError != "") {
            throw req.fileValidationError;
        }
        console.log(req.body.body)
        req.body.body = req.body;
        let qrr =  'INSERT INTO listproperty (Type,  plotNo, location,  sqft, sellType,  facing, price, BedRoom, BAthRoom,  Parking, date, Description, src)VALUES("'+req.body.Type+'","'+req.body.plotNo+'","'+req.body.location+'","'+req.body.sqft+'","'+req.body.sellType+'","'+req.body.facing+'", "'+req.body.price+'","'+req.body.BedRoom+'","'+req.body.BAthRoom+'","'+req.body.Parking+'","'+req.body.date+'","'+req.body.Description+'","'+req.body.src+'");'

    
        db.query(qrr, (err1, res1) => {
            if(err1)console.log(err1);
            else {
                res.send({
                    message: 'Data inserted',
                    body:res1
                })
            }
        })
    });
```

```
newProperty : any = new FormGroup({
    Type: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
    sellType: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
    facing: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
    src: new FormControl(''),
    plotNo: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    location: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    price: new FormControl(Validators.required),
    sqft: new FormControl(Validators.required),
    BedRoom: new FormControl(Validators.required),
    BAthRoom: new FormControl(Validators.required),
    Parking: new FormControl(Validators.required),
    Description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    date: new FormControl([Validators.required]),
  });

  // On file Select
  onChange(event: any) {
    this.newProperty.value.src  = event.target.files;
    //console.log(event);
    
    // this.file = event.target.files[0];
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getPropertyType()
    this.sellType = this.data.getSellType();
    let x = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('property')
    
    // if (x) {
    //   var d=this.data.getSingleData(x)
    //   console.log(d);
    //   setTimeout(() => {
    //     this.newProperty.patchValue(d)
    //     // this.newProperty.setControl('src')
    //   }, 1000);
    // }
  }
  getPropertyType() {
    console.log("res", this.sql.getPlotType());
    this.sql.getPlotType().subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
       this.plotType.push( res[i].propertyType);
      }
   // this.plotType =res  
   });
  }
  addNew() {
    if (this.newProperty.invalid) {
      alert('fill all details');
      return;
    }
    var data = [];
    //JSON.parse(this.newProperty.value)
    this.sql.addplotdata(this.newProperty.value).subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
       for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        data.push( res);
      }
      console.log("data");
   // this.plotType =res  
   });
   
    console.log(this.newProperty.value);
    // this.data.addData(this.newProperty.value);
    //this.newProperty.reset();
    this.router.navigate(['add-property']);
  }


  addplotdata(value: any): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post(this.addPropUrl, {value, "image" :value.src});
} // Backend.ts
```

---

Hello, I am wrking on nodejs . i got response from frontend post request. all dataa is getting but upload file data showing null. {} Pleasse see images
Hello, I am wrking on nodejs . i got response from frontend post request. all dataa is getting but upload file data showing null. {} Pleasse see images
Hello, I am wrking on nodejs . i got response from frontend post request. all dataa is getting but upload file data showing null. {} Pleasse see images

Comment: Can you share angular code as well, i think you are missing form data.

Comment: not sure about angular but all i can check is you havent use form-data here in header so basically whenever we need to send a file to the server we always have to use form-data